# WebSocket Programming in Java: client server communication issue

Tags: java, websocket

I am trying to implement simple WebSocket program using Java Web Application.

However, not able to establish communication between client and server.

Can anybody help me?

**Web Server**: Tomcat

**client code:** jsp/javascrip

```
<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" value="" id="message" /> <br /> <input
        type="submit" value="Start" onclick="start()" />
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webSocket;
    var uri = 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ZebraHosting/testwebsocket';
    alert('ur url is ' + uri);
    function connect() {

        if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            alert('I am in Websocket in window');
            websocket = new WebSocket(uri);
        } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
            websocket = new MozWebSocket(uri);
            alert('I am in MozWebsocket in window');
        } else {
            alert('WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
            return;
        }

        webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
            alert('I am onerror');
            onError(event);
        };

        webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
            alert('I am onopen');
            onOpen(event);
        };

        webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
            alert('I am onmessage');
            onMessage(event);
        };

        webSocket.onclose = function(event) {
            alert('I am onclose');
            onClose(event);
        };

    }
    function onMessage(event) {
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += '<br />'
                + event.data;
    }

    function onOpen(event) {
        alert("function onOpen " );
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = 'Connection established';
    }

    function onError(event) {
        alert("Error ocurred " );
    }

    function start() {
        alert("function start " );
        webSocket.send(document.getElementById('message').value);
        return false;
    }

    function onClose(event) {
        alert("function onClose" );
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = 'Connection closed';
    }

    connect();
</script>
```

**Server Code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/testwebsocket")
public class WebSocketTest {

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // Print the client message for testing purposes
    System.out.println("Received: " + message);
    // Send the first message to the client
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("replay from server for :" + message);
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen() {
    System.out.println("Client connected");
}

@OnClose
public void onClose() {
    System.out.println("Connection closed");
 }}
```

Comment: so what logs are printed on client and server?

Comment: @wero No logs as of now, I think nothing works after "function start()"

Comment: I'll post you tomorrow a working example (if it's not already solved).

Comment: @Gero Yes We are still working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typos in your code: You create `WebSocket` objects and assign it to variable `websocket` but later use variable `webSocket`.

Comment: Thanks for catch but still no output. one more question I have is the server class is normal Java class in this case do I need to deploy the war file every time? as what I am doing currently is just executing the above jsp page from eclipse.

Comment: by updating Typo webSocket --> websocket, program run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think @ApplicationScoped annotation is missing for server side class.

See this tutorial http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code, let me try and test. will feedback in any case [PASS/FAIL]

Comment: hi Ivan, by updating Typo webSocket --> websocket, program run correctly.